# Splitting huge XSDs?

Tags: xsd

I have this big huge XSD which contains many complex elements.

I want to split this huge XSD into smaller XSDs, containing the complex elements as standalone XSDs.

Are there any tools for this?

Comment: why not do it manually? it's not difficult.

Comment: ehm, its somewhat difficult for me.
heehehheheh

Answer (score 0):

Altova's [XmlSpy](http://www.altova.com/xml-editor/) doesn't provide an automated splitter but its graphical interface does allow you to copy/paste your types and elements easily from one XSD to another.